# How to pass a variable to class based views (ListView)

Tags: python, django, django-views

**My Views.py code**

```
class ListaFuncionariosView(ListView):
    model = Funcionarios
    template_name = '../templates/funcionarios/lista_funcionarios.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    ordering = ['FuncionarioCartao']
    queryset = Funcionarios.objects.filter(EmpresaCodigo=1)
    funcionarios_number = Funcionarios.objects.aggregate(Count('FuncionarioCartao'))
```

**My HTML**

```
<h1>Good Morning</h1>
   Exists: {{funcionarios_number}}
    <br>
    {{funcionarios}}
```

I would like to show the total number of registered employees in my db table (in the HTML file below), but I don't know how to put variables in class based views, in this case ListView. I'm using 4.0 Django

I tried put: funcionarios_number = Funcionarios.objects.aggregate(Count('FuncionarioCartao')) in bellow of my class, but this is not showed in my html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By aggregating at the class-level, the query will run when you *start* the server, and the count will thus always remain that exact number.

You can define this in a function:

```
class ListaFuncionariosView(ListView):
    model = Funcionarios
    template_name = '../templates/funcionarios/lista_funcionarios.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    ordering = ['FuncionarioCartao']
    queryset = Funcionarios.objects.filter(EmpresaCodigo=1)

    def funcionarios_number(self):
        return Funcionarios.objects.aggregate(total=Count('FuncionarioCartao'))[
            'total'
        ]
```

and then access the function in the view in the template:

```
{{ view.functionarios_number }}
```